# why can my svelte component print a json object but not a property on the object?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

i have a really simple component that looks like this:

```
    <script>
        export let task
    </script>
    
    {console.log("task-component, task:",task,"name:",task.name)}
    <td class="task-name">{task.name}</td>
```

when the component runs, the object is available but I can't access any of it's properties... here is what this looks like in the console:

> task-component, task: {"id":"638342774551207408","idx":-1,"name":"test 1013 @ 1335p"} name: undefined

How is this possible?  Clearly the task object is initialized at the time the console.log statement runs.  So why can't I access any properties of the object?

This has got to be so simple, but looking at tons of examples I can't see anything wrong.

UPDATE1:  I found a hack solution, which is to call JSON.parse on every task object before i need to access it.  This does not seem correct though (particularly for DRY considerations).

HACK (in Tasks.svelte):

```
    <script>
        import Task from "$lib/Task.svelte";
        import { parse } from "svelte/compiler";
        export let tasks = []
    </script>
    
    <table class="task-list stack-large" aria-labelledby="list-heading">
        {#each tasks as task}
        <tr class="task">
            {task=JSON.parse(task)}   <!-- HERE'S THE HACK, how to not do this? -->
            <Task {task}/>
            {console.log("added task:",task,"task-name:",task.name)}
        </tr>
        {/each}
    </table>
```

UPDATE2: some people asked where tasks are pulled in from, here is this route:

```
    <script>
    
    import Tasks from '$lib/Tasks.svelte'
    let tasks = []
    const fetchTasks = async() =>  {
        var response = await fetch('https://localhost:7070/list');
        var result = await response.json();
    
        //var result = result.map((jsonObject) => {
        //  return JSON.parse(jsonObject);
        //});
    
        return result;
        
    }
    
    let taskPromise = fetchTasks();
    
    </script>
    
    {#await taskPromise}
        <h4>Loading task data...</h4>
    {:then tasks}
        {console.log("loaded-task-data: ",tasks)}
    
        <Tasks {tasks} />
    {:catch err}
        <h3>Error while loading task data, {err}</h3>
    {/await}
```

Comment: Where are the task objects coming from?

Comment: @H.B. They're pulled in via another api by the parent components.  I attached the route showing how this is being done in 'UPDATE2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this wasn't actually an issue with svelte.

I guess either response.json (or JSON.parse) looks at the content-type.

My backend server was pushing out json but not setting content type.   When I forced type to appplication/json, it worked.

Backend isn't in svelte or JS but dotnet, here's what changed:

```
    [HttpGet("list")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetTasks()
    {
     //...
     //return Ok(objects);  // <-- data is same but content-type was plaintext by default
     return Content(JSONConvert.SerializeObjects(objects),"application/json"); // <-- this was the fix
    }
```